# java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, string, cast, integer

Estoy intentando guardar los valores de una tabla jTable llamada *tblMatriz* en una matriz *[int]* llamada *ady*.

Con esta accion, obtengo un numero de un text field para determinar el tamaño para la matriz (cuadrada):

```
private void GenerarMatrizActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        int n = Integer.parseInt(txtn.getText());
        int [][] matriz = new int [n][n];

        this.MostrarMatriz(matriz, n);
    }
```

Este es el metodo mostrar matriz:

```
public void MostrarMatriz(int matriz[][], int n){
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)tblMatriz.getModel();
        model.setRowCount(n); //Filas
        model.setColumnCount(n);//Columnas
        for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                tblMatriz.setValueAt(matriz[i][j], i, j);
                
            }
        }
        txtArista.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Con esta accion del btnGuardar mando a traer de nuevo el valor del text field para crear una nueva matriz y poder almacenar los valores del jTable.

```
private void btnGuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        int n = Integer.parseInt(txtn.getText());
        int [][] ady = new int [n][n];
        this.GuardarMatriz(ady, n);
    }
```

Y este es el metodo para guardar los valores del jTable en la nueva matriz

```
public void GuardarMatriz(int ady[][], int n){
        for (int i = 0; i < tblMatriz.getRowCount(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tblMatriz.getRowCount(); j++) {
               ady[i][j] = (int) tblMatriz.getValueAt(i, j); //En esta linea tengo el error
            }
        }
        for(int x=0; x<ady.length; x++){
            for(int y=0; y<ady.length; y++){
                System.out.print(ady[x][y]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```

Ya que netbeans me indicaba castear el valor obtenido de la celda en la posicion *i* y *j* para poder almacenarlo en la matriz, pero al hacerlo y ejecutar el programa obtengo el siguiente error:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Adjunto una imagen para ejemplificar como es mi form:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Oscar, bien el trabajo que tomaste en documentar tu pregunta pero creo que tiene informacion que sobra. Pienso que deberias dejar solo el codigo del metodo "GuardarMatriz" que es donde tienes el problema, e indicar los tipos de datos de todas las variables que participan en la sentencia que te causa el error; para tu caso indicar de que tipo es la variable "tblMatriz" .

Comment: Aunque adelantandome un poco creo que el problema es que haces casteo "(int)tblMatriz.getValueAt(i, j)" de una cadena, y deberias hacer parseo: "Integer.Parse(tblMatriz.getValueAt(i, j))" en la linea que te causa el error. Es importante saber el tipo de la variable tblMatriz para saber que tipo de dato devuelve getValueAt(i, j), aunque sospecho que es string.

Comment: Lo sé, es que algunas veces me han indicado poca información, pero gracias por el consejo. Verás, ya había intentado hacer un parseo, pero el error es diferente, y me indica que no es posible convertir un objeto a un String.

Comment: Por eso te digo que " Es importante saber el tipo de la variable tblMatriz para saber que tipo de dato devuelve getValueAt(i, j)" y poder solucionar tu inquetud. Puedes depurar la ejecucion colocando un punto de interrupcion en la linea en la que tienes el problema e inspecionar que valor esta retornando el metodo getValueAt(i, j) ?

Comment: Intente con `int x = (int) tblMatriz.getValueAt(1, 1);` y obtengo que `x = (int) 0`

Comment: En la palabra *Parse* obtengo un `cannot find symbol`

Comment: Corrijo. Es  Integer.parseInt(tblMatriz.getValueAt(i, j).toString());

Comment: YA FUNCIONOOO, muchas gracias Mauricio!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que nada lo recomendable es poner el código en un `try{}catch(NumberFormatExeption e){}` para que captures el error y no se detenga la ejecución del programa.

```
try{
   int n = Integer.parseInt(txtn.getText().trim());
   int [][] ady = new int [n][n];
   this.GuardarMatriz(ady, n);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Por otro lado recuerda que al convertir en entero no debe existir espacios ni ningún carácter que lo modifique, para eliminar espacios en blanco que puedes haber puesto accidentalmente en la sección del botón agrégale justo cuando conviertes `int n = Integer.parseInt(txtn.getText().trim());` como esta en la parte superior.

Y si por algún motivo estás usando TextField del paquete AWT, lo que debes hacer es utilizar JTextField porque el paquete SWING mejora el rendimiento comparado con AWT.

Por otro lado JTable.getValueAt(i, j) devuelve un objeto y en este caso te esta devolviendo un String eso quiere decir que esta tomando en cuenta la cabecera de la tabla, para probarlo haz un `System.out.println(tblMatriz.getValueAt(i, j));` y si eso es correcto debes simplemente iniciar `i` y `j` en `1`

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en la línea `ady[i][j] = (int) tblMatriz.getValueAt(i, j);` me retorna un String como valor de la celda de la jTable, y aunque haga un cast para Integer, me sale ese error de conversión: `java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`

Comment: No entiendo cual es tu duda. Tú mismo te estás dando la respuesta. `tblMatriz.getValue` te da un String. Una instancia de String no se puede "castear" a un Integer ya que no tienen relación de clase/subclase. Tienes que parsearla con `Integer.parseInt`, igual que haces en otros sitios.